# F# class assign an object value to another object

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, oop, f#

Coming from a C# background, I'm trying to assign an instance of a class to another instance of a class in F# but I'm getting the error 'Type Initialisation Exception'

My Code is

```
//filename is CCPType.fs

module CCPType =

    type CCPClass() = class
        let mutable p = Unchecked.defaultof<int>
        let mutable d = Unchecked.defaultof<int[,]>

        member self.P
            with get () = p
            and set (value) = p <- value

        member self.D
            with get () = d
            and set (value) = d <- value

    end

//filename is Programme.fs

Module Start =

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv = 
        let record = FileParser.ParseTextToCCPRecord(text) // returns CCPClass
        let z = Optimiser.Execute(record) //arg is of type CCPClass

//filename is Optimiser.fs

module Optimiser =

    let mutable ccpDataSet = CCPClass()
```

The following snippets are all part of Optimiser.fs within the module Optimiser. I've tried the following

```
    let Execute record =
        ccpDataSet <- record
```

and I've also tried

```
    let Execute(record: CCPClass) =
        ccpDataSet = new CCPClass()
        ccpDataSet.P <- record.P
        ccpDataSet.D <- record.D
```

and I've also tried

```
    let Execute(record: CCPClass) =
        ccpDataSet <- new CCPClass()
        ccpDataSet.P <- record.P
        ccpDataSet.D <- record.D
```

and I've also tried

```
    let Execute record =
        ccpDataSet.P <- record.P
        ccpDataSet.D <- record.D
```

and I've tried quite a few different ways but I still can't copy one instantiated class to another.

I get the error, 'An unhandled exception of type "System.TypeInitializationException"'.

'"ccpDataSet" threw an exception of type "System.TypeInitializationException"'.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: where is that error thrown? Can you provide a minimal but complete example showing the problem? - I guess I don't have to tell you that this is pretty much anti-idiomatic F# here

Comment: What's `InnerException`?

Comment: The inner exception is {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at <StartupCode$CCP>.$Optimiser..cctor() in D:\CCP\Optimiser.fs:line 19}

Comment: Line 19 is  let mutable private OpenD : bool[] = Array.zeroCreate<bool> ccpDataSet.D.Length

Comment: @Carsten yeah it is but I'm new at F# since my primary background is C++ and C#

Comment: @user4633919 which is perfectly fine but you should do yourself a favor: please don't try to copy C# code as is - you will be very disappointed - instead learn FP and then you will be disappointed about C# ;)

Comment: @Carsten I do love F# I'm learning thanks to you and others. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Fyodor and Carsten, I figured it out.

```
let mutable private OpenD : bool[] = Array.zeroCreate<bool> ccpDataSet.D.Length
```

Since I'm new to F# it doesn't behave like C#, I was trying to set the length of OpenD to a null instance. Changed it to 0 and it works :)

Comment: That's not quite correct. When initializing your CCPClass instance, you are using `Unchecked.defaultof<int[,]>` as the value for `d`. Just like in C#, the default value of a reference type is null, hence you got a NullReferenceException when you tried to dereference it with `ccpDataSet.D.Length`.

Comment: and of course the `D.Length` was not even in the question ... that's why you should always provide a minimal example demonstrating your problem!

Comment: Additionally, the idiomatic F# version of copying all or part of a type would be: `type Record =
    {
        p:int;
        d:int[,];
    }` for the type definition, 
`let record = { p = 0; d = null }` for creating an instance, and
`let recordCopy = { record with p = 5 }` to get a modified copy.

Comment: @ChrisHannon Originally I had it initialised with Array.zeroCreate 10 but that resulted in the same error so I switched over to this.

Comment: @ChrisHannon I'll try out the examples you've given. Ta.

Comment: @ChrisHannon tried those examples but the create a local instance and do not apply to the globally declared ccpDataSet within that module. ccpDataSet <- record works seems to work fine so far.